# SSRS multivalue parameter default selection

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, parameter-passing, ssrs-2008-r2, multivalue

I have a SSRS report and it have one multi valued parameter. I need to assign some default values into that param during report rendering time. The multi valued paramater having hundreds of data. I write a procedure for getting default values and assigned that SP in that paramter.(Default values -> specify values form query).

But the problem is when the procedure written for getting default values, have more than 10 rows it is not selecting. If it have less than 10 then the multi value is working

Comment: Is it always causing an issue on 10 records?  This problem does not present itself in SSRS 2008R2 using just a list of numbers (12 values can be multi-selected from a Default Values dataset for example).  What data are you multi-selecting?  Is it just numbers?  Character strings might contain commas that would interrupt the multi-select operation.

Comment: If the **default** values include any values that are not part of the **available** values, it will **not** select **any** values.

Comment: thanks Hannover and Jonnus for your comments. It is due to in the default values data set includes values that are not part of the available values.